# Installing Qt on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: update, qt

I'm trying to install Qt Creator to my Raspberry Pi 3 for a GUI project. However when I use the command

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

it gives an error saying that:

```
E:Unable to fetch some archives,maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

As I considered the advice of my raspberry pi I tried the command `sudo apt-get update`. However I got errors again saying

```
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Apparently I am doing something wrong and any help will be appreciated.

Edit for clearance: Normally I was able to get updates without any errors. However after trying to install Qt it started giving errors as I tried to update.

Comment: So did you try with `--fix-missing`?

Comment: Yes, I just tried it and it gave no error.  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. However, it still fails to update or install the qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not particularly sure why you are trying to install that package, the [App Note](https://wiki.qt.io/Apt-get_Qt4_on_the_Raspberry_Pi) for installing Qt Creator on Raspberry Pi says to install

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install qtcreator
```

Some extra packages are also listed.

I personally keep Qt Creator on my PC which can compile programs a lot faster during development and then follow their [Build Guide](https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt_5.4.1_on_a_Raspberry_Pi) so I can compile it naively on a releasable version.

Comment: It gets stuck at first command. It gives the error "Unable to fetch some arhives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?"

Comment: And what happens when you run the two suggestions?

Comment: Update fails, and fix missing suggestion returns "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. ". However I am still unable to install qt. I will try to reinstall Raspberian from scratch probably, I suspect this might be due to corrupted OS.I had no problems three days ago.

Comment: if `sudo apt-get update` is failing then it sounds like you have a bigger problem with your OS. When you say it fails what error message is displayed? And are you definitely connected to the internet? (try `ping 8.8.8.8`).

If you have installed lots of packages already then I would try installing from a clean version of Rasbian on a separate SD card, if not just reformat your current SD card.

Comment: I reformatted my SD. Now, I have installed the Qt without any hardship or any problems. I don't know what was the problem but it is solved, I guess. Thanks for help. @pfl

Comment: For people who ended up here by the power of google. Use the command lines in the answer to download qt. It works fine. My problem was due to another problem which I cannot find the source. Formatting the SD card solved the problem. Thanks @pfl again.

Comment: No worries, have fun with Qt

Comment: What if you don't want to use Qt4? Qt4 is EoL and unsupported.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working way to install Qt5. For Qt5 there is no need for dev-tools. So this command is not relevant:

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools
```

The two commands needed to install Qt5 fully are:

1. `sudo apt-get install qt5-default` (installs Qt version **5.7.1**)
2. `sudo apt-get install qtcreator`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please contribute first so you get enough points and then comment, not the other way around!

Comment: @Greenonline: Appreciate your edit &  team spirit :) Cheers.

Comment: Hi, it seems, nowadays there is no way to install qt5-default, it writes: "Package qt5-default is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source". Could you please help with it? I'm noob in question of Qt configuration, any help will be useful, googling provides too complicated answers to me